# php, apache & .htaccess: include php configuration file globally

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have a php project which has a configuration file config.php that stores config information like database info, directories, etc.

normally we would include this config file at the top of every php page like require_once(".../config.php); however, i have found a way to do this by creating  a .htaccess file and include this:

```
php_value  auto_prepend_file  /home/public_html/..../config.php
```

this works fine until i transferred it to the shared hosting. apparently, this shared hosting allows us to change the PHP version from 4x to 5x. After changing to 5x, i realised they have created a .htaccess file with the following content:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$"> # phpvs v5
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php # phpvs v5
</FilesMatch> # phpvs v5
```

with this, it ignores the include path to the config file.. how can i go about fixing this? i certainly do not wanna include my config.php in every php files.

Answer (score 2):

An htaccess file is not restricted to containing a single directive.  You can have both.

Answer (score 2):

> normally we would include this config file at the top of every php page like require_once(".../config.php); however, i have found a way to do this by creating a .htaccess file and include this

Probably not the wisest move.  It is more stable and portable to do this in your PHP than to rely on .htaccess.  Relying on .htaccess means if your web server is changed or reconfigured it's likely to stop working (as you found).

I know it doesn't answer your question but I would consider going back to doing this using require_once() in the appropriate PHP files.

Comment: hmm i understand that. wat about an alternative way in php that doesnt need to include in all pages??

Comment: A complex CMS will have just one main PHP script which handles all requests for pages then hands off control to various modules based on which page was requested, so you would only need to include your config.php in that file.  But yeah, it depends on what you're doing.